# Different result when using g:link and g.link

Tags: grails, gsp, taglib, grails-2.3

When I am using

```
<g:link url="https://www.google.co.in">Google 1</g:link>
```

this gives me correct result, a link to https://www.google.co.in.

```
Google 1
```

But when I am using

```
${g.link(url: "https://www.google.co.in") { 'Google 2' }}
```

this gives me

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in">Google 2</a>
```

which is a text not a link.

I have tried `encodeAsHTML()` and `decodeHTML()` but result is same.

**What I am doing wrong here? How I can get the link instead of text?**

Using `grails 2.3.7` and have `grails.views.default.codec = "html"` in my Config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably seeing a security feature in grails: "Cross Site Scripting (XSS) Prevention"

In a nutshell, try (untested):

```
${raw(g.link(url: "https://www.google.co.in") { 'Google 2' })}
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#xssPrevention for more. All of that section is worth reading 'cos there are several configuration options available.

Answer (score 2):

This information can be useful, it is from grails documentation

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/security.html

Each tag library created has the opportunity to specify a default codec used to encode output from the tag library using the "defaultEncodeAs" property:

```
static defaultEncodeAs = 'html'
```

Encoding can also be specified on a per tag basis using "encodeAsForTags":

```
static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: 'raw']
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `grails.views.default.codec='html'` in `Config.groovy` to get HTML escaping by default on all `${expressions}` in the application.

To disable HTML encoding for your gsp set `<%@page defaultCodec="none" %>` in the top of your gsp.